# Unable to receive messages from SAP using WCF-SAP adapter in BizTalk Server 2013

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

We are not able to receive messages from SAP using WCF-SAP adapters on BizTalk Server 2013. The following is the error message

Error Description:

```
The adapter "WCF-SAP" raised an error message. Details "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23'
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.TypedIdocBodyWriter.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundCountractReply.CleanupAfterSendingResponseToSapForClassicRfc()
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundCountractReply.CleanupAfterSendingResponseToSap()
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundCountractReply.ReplyUsingClassicRfc(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a DLL.  Have you verified that the sapnco DLL version 3.0.0.42 with Public Key 50436dca5c7f7d23 is in your GAC?

Comment: did you receive some messages before from SAP? if it's a new setup as suggested by @Dijkgraaf you have check/install the missed dll to the GAC.